# Matrices issue in a game in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Why several matrices appear and not only one? Also, I can't enlarge even though it increases 1,1,1,1.

My code:

```
import os
import time
import random

from Tkinter import *
import os

def leftKey(event):
        e_b(-1)

def rightKey(event):
        e_b(1)

def escKey(event):
        root.quit()

def refresh():
        time.sleep(0.03)
        clear = lambda: os.system('clear')
        for i in range(0,len(m)):
                for j in range(0,len(m)):
                        if m[i][j] == 1:
                                print '#',
                        elif m[i][j] == 2:
                                print '=',
                        elif m[i][j] == 3:
                                print '*',
                        else:
                                print ' ',
                print ''

        root.after(30, refresh) 

def e_b(x):
        for i in range(0,len(b)):
                f = b[i][0]
                c = b[i][1]
                m[f][c] = 0

        if x == -1:
                if b[0][1] > 0:
                        for i in range(0,len(b)):
                                b[i][1] += x
        elif x == 1:
                if b[len(b)-1][1] < len(m)-1:
                        for i in range(0,len(b)):
                                b[i][1] += x

        for i in range(0,len(b)):
                f = b[i][0]
                c = b[i][1]
                m[f][c] = 2


m = [   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

b = [[len(m)-1,0],[len(m)-1,1],[len(m)-1,2]]
e_b(0)

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
root.bind('<Left>', leftKey)
root.bind('<Right>', rightKey)
root.bind('<Escape>', escKey)
frame.pack()

root.after(30, refresh)
#root.after(30, mov_ball)
root.mainloop()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbkZ2.png)

I want it to look this way or bigger

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC6Eu.png)

I'm working on ball movement.

Comment: I think `for j in range(0,len(m))` in `refresh()` should be `for j in range(0,len(m[i]))`.  Also `if b[len(b)-1][1] < len(m)-1` after `elif x == 1` in `e_b(x)` should be `if b[len(b)-1][1] < len(m[b[0][0]])-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix has size `10x6` but you print `6x6`

In Python you don't have to use `range(len())` if you don't change value in matrix.

```
for row in m:
    for val in row:
        if val == 1:
            print '#',
        elif val == 2:
            print '=',
        elif val == 3:
            print '*',
        else:
            print ' ',
    print    # you don't need empty string
```

If you need more `elif` then it is easier to use list (or dict)

```
blocks = [" ", "#", "=", "*"]
blocks_length = len(blocks)

for row in m:
    for val in row:
        if val < blocks_length:
            print blocks[val],
        else:
            print '?',
    print
```

or if you sure you don't use val bigger or equl then  blocks_length

```
blocks = [" ", "#", "=", "*"]
blocks_length = len(blocks)

for row in m:
    for val in row:
        print blocks[val],
    print
```

But question is why to use `0`, `1` in matrix if we can use `" "` and `"#"`

```
m = [
  ["#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"],
  [" ", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", " ", " "],
  [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
]
```

---

**BTW:**

You create function `clear`

```
clear = lambda:os.system('clear')
```

but you don't execute it

```
clear()
```

so it doesn't clear screen